# How to get the values in comma separated using joins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on SQL, I have two tables

```
EId    Ename
 1     john
 2     alex
 3     piers
 4     sara
```

And the second table is

```
 PID   PNAME  EID
 1     mcndd  1
 2     carter 1
 3     leare  2
 4      jain  2
```

The result should be

```
EID  count  PID
 1     2     1
 1     2     2
 2     2     3
 2     2     4
```

I want a query for this.i had tried like this

```
SELECT  t1.EID, COUNT(t1.EID) count,PID
 from Employertable t1
 INNER   JOIN persontable P ON P.EID=t1.EID
Group By t1.EID Having Count(T1.EID) > 1
```

Comment: Please read about `join` and `group by` those will give you, your answer.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @marc_s i just edited i tried like this i am getting PID is not valid and not containing any aggregate function

Comment: When using the `GROUP BY` clause, every column in your `SELECT` list **must be** either handled by an aggregate (`COUNT`,  `SUM`, `AVG` etc.), or if that's not the case, it **has to be** mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause. So in your case, you **must** use `GROUP BY t1.EID, PID` -

Comment: @marc_s i agree with you and thanks for reply i was new for the sql i will try to learn thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions. With those functions you can combine aggregated data with non-aggregated data:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( EID INT )
DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( PID INT, EID INT )

INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 4 )
INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 ),
        ( 4, 2 )


SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    t1.EID ,
                    COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.EID ) AS C ,
                    t2.PID
          FROM      @t1 t1
                    JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.EID = t1.EID
        ) t
WHERE   t.C > 1
```

Output:

```
EID C   PID
1   2   1
1   2   2
2   2   3
2   2   4
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply @Giorgi Nakeuri let me try plz

Comment: hi @@Giorgi Nakeuri but i am getting defferent result i had with id 2  count =14 records but the result returning 84

Comment: could u plz explain me about "COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.EID ) AS C ,"

Comment: @Sadda-shutu, you can edit your question with data where statement fails. And explain what you wish to see for that data as result. COUNT(*) will count all rows with same EID in table 2 and put that result for each row with that EID

Comment: sory sory @Giorgi Nakeuri it was my mistake i wana say one thing  to you,you are super u saved my lot time thank you very much

Comment: can you please sugget me to best tuetorial or website to learn best query wirting  sql thanks

Comment: @Sadda-shutu, 70-461 Training Kit